# Why does the pointer only work for normal scanf rather than a custom function?

Tags: c, input

I went to plan an input function for my language and it is called `take()`. I first built it in C and Python, but for sake in this question, I will use C:

```
char *take(char *text) {
    char result[256];
    printf("%s", text); scanf("%s", result);
    return result;
}
```

It's what I had in mind, and I want to try it in an actual program:

```
int main() {
    char name[256];
    name = take("What's your name? ");
    sayLn("Hello, " + name + "."); // The say() function, except it prints out a new line too
}
```

But I got 4 errors when I tried compiling, 2 of them were because of the input function:

```
Hello.c:13:12: error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'result' returned [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return result;
           ^~~~~~
Hello.c:18:10: error: array type 'char [256]' is not assignable
    name = take("What's your name? ");
    ~~~~ ^
```

However, if I try the source code into the normal program, it works!

```
int main() {
    char name[256];
    printf("What's your name? "); scanf("%s", name);
    sayLn("Hello there!"); // Had to change this because of the other 2 errors
}
```

Q: **Why is it like this? How do I fix it?**

Comment: Aside: `char result[256];` will die when you return from the function, so returning a pointer to it is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  You cannot assign a `char *` to an array.  Typically, you would do something like `int take(const char *prompt, char *result, size_t siz)` and pass the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", result);` has exactly the same problem as `gets`.  Do not do that.

Comment: All user input is tricky, a sad fact of life. `scanf("%255s", result);` will prevent buffer overflow, but if user enters `Betty Jo` it will only read `Betty`.

Comment: scanf can be used, but `scanf("%s")` cannot be used safely.  In this case, it seems odd that you will prevent a user from having whitespace in their name, so any form of `%s` seems inappropriate.

Comment: @BPML Another way of reading the input is `fgets()` or `fread()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a pointer to a local variable, and you cannot assign a pointer to an array.  The way this sort of thing would usually be done is to pass the address of the result.  I really don't think `scanf` is the right thing to use here, since it seems odd to prevent the name from containing whitespace, but for the sake of demonstration, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
take(const char *prompt, char *result, size_t siz)
{
        char fmt[32];
        printf("%s", prompt);
        assert(siz < 10e28);  /* %Ns for N < SIZE_MAX must fit in fmt */
        sprintf(fmt, "%%%zus", siz - 1);
        return scanf(fmt, result);
}

int
main(void)
{
        char name[256];
        if( take("What's your name? ", name, sizeof name) == 1 ) {
                printf("Hello, %s.\n", name);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Note that you should use `scanf("%s", ...)` the same way you should use `gets`.  That is, you should only use it as a demonstration of bad code.  You must always use a maximum width in the specifier to prevent overflow.  That is, instead of `%s` which will write an arbitrarily large amount of data, you should use `%Ns` (eg `%255s`) where N is one less than the size of the array that scanf will write to.

Comment: Kudos for the effort to construct the correct `scanf()` conversion specification. You might also use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` for example's sake.

Comment: @chqrlie It's a reasonable point.  Rather than that, I'll add an assertion.

Comment: Then why not `assert(siz < 10e29)` for a buffer size of 32 bytes?

Comment: 1 for `%`, 1 for `s`, 1 for the terminating null, and 1 to compensate for the inevitable off by one error! (I didn't want to think too hard about how many digits are in the string).  If anyone needs 10^28 characters for their name, there are other issues to worry about!

Comment: Actually I meant `assert(siz < 1e29)` which is equivalent to `assert(siz < 10e28)` anyway.

Comment: Then there is a scenario where `siz < 10e28` might cause an off by one error: as per the C Standard, ***6.3.1 Arithmetic operands** [...] If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.* So converting a huge `size_t` type to `double` might a produce floating point number just below `10e28` whereas `10e28` must produce the closest `double` value, which may be larger. Floating point arithmetic is so tricky :)

Comment: @chqrlie Oh!  I didn't even realize that I had made that error.  I had intended `1e28` from the start to avoid having to think too much about the floating point issues and wound up with it incorrect.  Probably safest to make it 1e25 and not even worry about anyone who needs a yotta byte for their name!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your approach:

- `take()` returns a pointer to a local automatic array: accessing it after the function returns has undefined behavior.
- you should store the return value of `take()` into a `char*` in `main()`.
- string concatenation is not possible with the `+` operator in C.

There are 2 ways to fix these problems:

- you can allocate a copy of the string in `take()` and return a pointer to that, but you will need to free this object after use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sayLn(const char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

char *take(const char *text) {
    char result[256];
    printf("%s", text);
    *result = '\0';  // return an empty string on input error
    scanf("%s", result);
    return strdup(result);
}

int main() {
    char message[300];
    char *name = take("What's your name? ");
    snprintf(message, sizeof message, "Hello, %s.", name);
    free(name);
    sayLn(message);  
    return 0;
}
```

- you can pass the destination array to `take`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sayLn(const char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

char *take(const char *prompt, char *result, size_t size) {
    char spec[32];
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    // construct a conversion specification that limits the input to avoid a buffer overflow
    snprintf(spec, sizeof spec, "%%%zus", size - 1);
    printf("%s", text);
    *result = '\0';  // return an empty string on input error
    scanf(spec, result);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    char name[256];
    char message[300];
    take("What's your name? ", name, sizeof name);
    snprintf(message, sizeof message, "Hello, %s.", name);
    sayLn(message);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good approach, except that you didn't use my `sayLn()` function, which I'm not mad about, but it does give me an understanding over string concatenation.

Comment: @BPML: you cannot use `sayLn()` as posted in your original attempt. I amended the answer showing how to concatenate strings.

Comment: Okay, then. At least it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a pointer:

```
int main() {
    char *name;
    name = take("What's your name? ");
    sayLn("Hello, there!");
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't actually resolve your error regarding stack memory being returned. Try fixing that yourself.

Comment: This only addresses the `main()` issue. There is still undefined behavior because `take()` returns a pointer to a local automatic array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a string formatted with arrays instead of a pointer.

Try this:

```
char *take(char *text) {
    printf("%s", text);
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    scanf("%s", result);
    return result;
}
```